# Help me identify this bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

I would appreciate if someone could help me identify this bike?
I am kindly short, and just afraid that I could not ride it.
Here is the image:
[image]

Comment: Just to be clear - your real question is - "will this bike fit me?" If this is your question it would be better to tell us how tall you are and your inseam measurement so we could tell you what size bike to look for. Finding out what kind of bike this is - identifying it - won't tell us what size it is because most models are made in more than one size.

Answer (score 1):

It is some sort of [mamachari](https://www.mamachari.co.uk/about-us/what-is-mamachari/) or [omafiets](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/omafiets) which are Japanese and Dutch respectively for "mother-bike" and "grandmother-bike"  Anyone can ride such a bike if it fits.

There is no specific branding or logos visible, so we have no way to determine a brand, but I can see:

- Internal gear hub, probably 3 speed
- Parcel racks front and rear, both highly robust.
- Low, step-through frame for ease of mounting
- Frame appears to be aluminium, for lightness.  Suggests relatively recent, last 20 years or so.
- Kickstand for parking like in photo, makes loading easier
- Integrated frame lock on rear wheel - common in Europe
- Integrated lighting mounts on the fork and head tube, BUT there is not permanently fitted light as per many European requirements.

As for fit - the saddle could move down some 50mm further.  There's a concertina cover on the stem, it might be able to move down a lot further, hard to tell.

Your best bet is ride it in person and see how you find it.  Looks like a perfectly serviceable shopping bike, though unlikely to be speedy or long-distance.